# Not able to use *ngIf in pop up

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I'm making a pop up in `angular` with primeng. The content of the pop up depends on two flags controlled by radio buttons. If one is true, a particular HTML has to be rendered and if other is true, other part has to be rendered. But if one is true, other part in not getting cleared form the pop up. My code is something like this:

**In .ts file:**

```
part1: boolean = false;
part2: boolean = false;

makeP1True() {
    this.part1=true;
    this.part2=false;
}

makeP2True() {
    this.part2=true;
    this.part1=false;
}
```

**in HTML file:**

```
<p-radioButton name="groupname" value="Part1" (onClick)="makeP1True()"></p-radioButton>

<p-radioButton name="groupname" value="Part2" (onClick)="makeP2True()"></p-radioButton>

<div *ngIf="part1">
    Show Part 1
 </div>

<div *ngIf="part2">
    Show Part 2
 </div>
```

Comment: There is nothing as `flase`

Comment: Can you try with: `<div *ngIf="part1 === true"></div>` and `<div *ngIf="part2 === true"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `part2` property as in you example

```
part1: boolean = false;
part1: boolean = false; // just name it to part2
```

template

```
<p-radioButton name="groupname" [value]="Part1" label="Part1" (onClick)="makeP1True()"></p-radioButton>
<p-radioButton name="groupname" [value]="Part2" label="Part2" (onClick)="makeP2True()"></p-radioButton>

<div *ngIf="part1">
    Show Part 1
 </div>

<div *ngIf="part2">
    Show Part 2
 </div>
```

component

```
export class AppComponent {
  part1: boolean = false;
  part2: boolean = false;

  makeP1True() {
    this.part1 = true;
    this.part2 = false;
  }

  makeP2True() {
    this.part2 = true;
    this.part1 = false;
  }
}
```

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-radiobutton-toggle)

> As a general note you can solve it with single  propert and relay on
>   p-radioButton to toggle the value

component

```
export class AppComponent {
  part1: boolean ;
}
```

template

```
<p-radioButton name="groupname" label="part1" [value]="true" [(ngModel)]="part1"></p-radioButton>
<p-radioButton name="groupname" label="part2" [value]="false" [(ngModel)]="part1"></p-radioButton>

<div *ngIf="part1 === true">
    Show Part 1
</div>

<div *ngIf="part1 === false">
    Show Part 2
</div>
```

[stackblitz example with single variable](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-radiobutton-toggle-2)

Answer (score 1):

By doing `*ngIf="part1"` you are actually just checking whether 'part1' is **truthy**, which means whether it exists or not. However, to see which item is selected, you would need to set a state variable such as `selected`.

I would suggest you simplify this by using a single function and [ngSwitch](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch). Here is a tutorial: https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular-2-ngswitch-directive/

With the `[ngSwitch]` directive you can specify an expression to be evaluated. With `*ngSwitchCase` you can specify the matcher. The syntax would be the closest to your code.

It would look like this:

**HTML**

```
<p-radioButton name="groupname" 
               value="Part1" 
               (onClick)="setPart('part1')">

</p-radioButton>

<p-radioButton name="groupname" 
               value="Part2" 
               (onClick)="setPart('part2')">
</p-radioButton>

<ng-container [ngSwitch]="selected">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'part1'">
      Show Part 1
  </div>

  <div *ngSwitchCase="'part2'">
      Show Part 2
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

**TS**

```
public selected: string;

public setPart(id: string): void {

     this.selected = id;
}
```

In this case both divs do something like this: `*ngIf = "selected === 'partX'`.

BTW: [`<ng-container>`](https://alligator.io/angular/ng-container-element/) lets you use directives such as `*ngIf`,`*ngSwitch` and so on without creating a new DOM elements. Great for building conditionals.

You can read up on all of this [in the official docs](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives)